# Jenkins Error SEVERE hudson.triggers.SafeTimerTask failed

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins 2.375.4
Podman Container running in RHEL-8 OS
Running the container under systemd service

Apr 18 11:39:19 rhrd0100lws004d.ncte.navy.local container-jenkins[2628014]: [72922.726s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start thread - pthread_create failed (EAGAIN) for attributes: stacksize: 1024k, guardsize: 0k, detached.
Apr 18 11:39:19 rhrd0100lws004d.ncte.navy.local container-jenkins[2628014]: 2023-04-18 11:39:19.832+0000 [id=51]        SEVERE        hudson.triggers.SafeTimerTask#run: Timer task hudson.model.Queue$MaintainTask@4bd07352 failed
Apr 18 11:39:19 rhrd0100lws004d.ncte.navy.local container-jenkins[2628014]: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached
Apr 18 11:39:19 rhrd0100lws004d.ncte.navy.local container-jenkins[2628014]:         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
Apr 18 11:39:19 rhrd0100lws004d.ncte.navy.local container-jenkins[2628014]:         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:798)
Apr 18 11:39:19 rhrd0100lws004d.ncte.navy.local container-jenkins[2628014]:         at hudson.model.Executor.start(Executor.java:844)
Apr 18 11:39:19 rhrd0100lws004d.ncte.navy.local container-jenkins[2628014]:         at hudson.model.Computer.startFlyWeightTask(Computer.java:1303)
Apr 18 11:39:19 rhrd0100lws004d.ncte.navy.local container-jenkins[2628014]:         at hudson.model.Queue.lambda$createFlyWeightTaskRunnable$1(Queue.java:1790)
Apr 18 11:39:19 rhrd0100lws004d.ncte.navy.local container-jenkins[2628014]:         at hudson.model.Queue.maintain(Queue.java:1578)
Apr 18 11:39:19 rhrd0100lws004d.ncte.navy.local container-jenkins[2628014]:         at hudson.model.Queue$MaintainTask.doRun(Queue.java:2909)
Apr 18 11:39:19 rhrd0100lws004d.ncte.navy.local container-jenkins[2628014]:         at hudson.triggers.SafeTimerTask.run(SafeTimerTask.java:94)
Apr 18 11:39:19 rhrd0100lws004d.ncte.navy.local container-jenkins[2628014]:         at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingScheduledExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingScheduledExecutorService.java:69)
Apr 18 11:39:19 rhrd0100lws004d.ncte.navy.local container-jenkins[2628014]:         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
Apr 18 11:39:19 rhrd0100lws004d.ncte.navy.local container-jenkins[2628014]:         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
Apr 18 11:39:19 rhrd0100lws004d.ncte.navy.local container-jenkins[2628014]:         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
Apr 18 11:39:19 rhrd0100lws004d.ncte.navy.local container-jenkins[2628014]:         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
Apr 18 11:39:19 rhrd0100lws004d.ncte.navy.local container-jenkins[2628014]:         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
Apr 18 11:39:19 rhrd0100lws004d.ncte.navy.local container-jenkins[2628014]:         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

Answer (score 0):

I changed the podman run with following parameter and that seemed to fix issue.
--pids-limit=0

See: https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/options/pids-limit.html